# How do you create a multidimensional numpy array from an iterable of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to create a numpy array from an iterable, which yields tuples of values, such as a database query.

Like so:

```
data = db.execute('SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM data')
A = np.array(list(data))
```

Is there a way faster way of doing so, without converting the iterable to a list first?

Comment: not sure if this works: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html

Comment: @Fabricator The documentation says that it creates a *1d* array from the iterable. In this case it would create an array of objects instead of a 2d array with 4 columns.

Comment: `np.loadtxt` is an example of creating an array from an iterable, namely a file. In simplified terms, it reads a line, makes a list from its substrings, and appends that to a list.  At the end it converts the list of lists to an array.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an experienced user of `numpy`, but here is a possible solution for the general question:

```
>>> i = iter([(1, 11), (2, 22)])
>>> i
<listiterator at 0x5b2de30>                    # a sample iterable of tuples
>>> rec_array = np.fromiter(i, dtype='i4,i4')  # mind the dtype
>>> rec_array                                  # rec_array is a record array
array([(1, 11), (2, 22)], 
    dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
>>> rec_array['f0'], rec_array[0]              # each field has a default name
(array([1, 2]), (1, 11))
>>> a = rec_array.view(np.int32).reshape(-1,2) # let's create a view
>>> a
array([[ 1, 11],
       [ 2, 22]])
>>> rec_array[0][1] = 23
>>> a                                          # a is a view, not a copy!
array([[ 1, 23],
       [ 2, 22]])
```

I assume that all columns are of the same type, otherwise rec_array is already what you want.

Concerning your particular case, I do not completely understand what is `db` in your example. If it is a cursor object, then you can just call its `fetchall` method and get a list of tuples. In most cases, the database library does not want to keep a partially read query result, waiting for your code processing each line, that is by the moment when the `execute` method returns, all data is already stored in a list, and there is hardly a problem of using `fetchall` instead of iterating `cursor` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Although technically not an answer to my question, I found a way to do what I am trying to do:

```
def get_cols(db, cols):
    def get_col(col):
        data = db.execute('SELECT '+col+' FROM data', dtype=np.float64)
        return np.fromiter((v[0] for v in data))

    return np.vstack([get_col(col) for col in cols]).T
```